# VBA issue : Simple operations with multiple types of variables

Tags: vba, excel, long-integer, multiplication

I encountered a very annoying issue while handling different types of variables in Excel 2010 in a VBA Function. I've tried the following code with ad without Excel Conversions thanks to some other questions about the same overflow issue (error 6), but it didnt worked out (I might have done it wrong, but I dont have my instructions anymore)

```
Function do_calculation(lig_desti As Integer, col_desti As Integer)
  Range(Cells(lig_desti, col_desti), Cells(lig_desti, col_desti)).Value = Range(Cells(lig_desti, col_desti - 3), Cells(lig_desti, col_desti - 3)).Value * (Range(Cells(lig_desti, col_desti - 1), Cells(lig_desti, col_desti - 1)).Value / Range(Cells(lig_desti, col_desti - 2), Cells(lig_desti, col_desti - 2)).Value)
End Function
```

Just to summarize, i want to do (for every line) D = A * (C / B).

The idea is that i have 3 columns of values, here are the first rows just to give you an idea:

```
A        B      C         D
2187    71,8    18
1050    78,65   18
1813    92,35   18
2379,45 94      18
```

So basically (unless i'm wrong) i have to deal with long, doubles and integers. Note that the "C" column will always contain the same value (18) and the A column may contain large integers superior to 20k or 30k

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If column B has decimals, you can't use `integer`.

Comment: Am i? When speaking of Integers i mainly referred to the "C" column

Comment: code given must run as part of macro; it is forbidden for code running as part of a worksheet function invocation to alter the sheet so Range(x,y).Value=2 will fail.

Comment: Also if it's `C/B` why do you have `/18` last??

Comment: You do not need Range(cells(x,y), cell(x,y)) just use Cells(x,y).  It's a single cell, no?

Comment: Oh really? Yes indeed it's single cell...  i'm going to try this then. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps

```
Sub WriteFormula(ByVal sh As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal lRow As Long, ByVal lColumn As Long)
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = sh.Cells(lRow, lColumn)

    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*(RC[-1]/RC[-2])"
End Sub

Sub Test()
    WriteFormula ActiveSheet, 1, 4
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll consider your way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

To do this in an easy way, you can use `Application.Caller`. To do it in a way it also can be used as array just use `Evaluate`.

put this into a **Module*:

```
Public Function do_calculation() As Variant
  With Application.Caller '.Cells '(1, 1)
    do_calculation = Evaluate(.Offset(, -3).Address & "*" & .Offset(, -1).Address & "/" & .Offset(, -2).Address)
  End With
End Function
```

then in D1 enter `=do_calculation()` and copy down. Or select the range D1:D4 and enter `=do_calculation()` but confirm it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

to just get the values directly, you need to do it via a `Sub` like this:

```
Sub do_calculation(rng As Range)
  With rng
    .Value = Evaluate(.Offset(, -3).Address & "*" & .Offset(, -1).Address & "/" & .Offset(, -2).Address)
  End With
End Sub
```

simply select the cells D1:D4 and run `do_calculation selection`.

Comment: This really helped me out ! Thanks a lot